# how to index a whole TYPO3 storage with ext:solr?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a TYPO3 8.7.17 installation with ext:`solr` 8.1.0 and ext:`solrfal` 4.2.1
The solr-server (6.6.3) is working as my pages become indexed and can be found.

Now I want to index all files from an additional storage (uid = 2)

I have this typoscript configuration:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    :
    index {
        :
        enableFileIndexing = 1
        enableFileIndexing {
            :
            storageContext = 1
            storageContext {
                2 {
                    languages = 0
                    fileExtensions = *
                    enableFields {
                    }
                    folders = *
                    excludeFolders =
                }
            }
            :
        }
        :
    }
}
```

and this scheduler tasks:
[image]

as you can see: the File Index Queue Worker has 0% progress and no files are indexed.

Also the solr admin console states only 7 documents, which are the indexed pages.

What is missing or needs other configuration?

---

**EDIT:**
as I have no access to ext:solrfal 5.1 I had to downgrade to
ext:solr 7.5.2
ext:solrfal 4.2.1
ext:tika 2.4.0

I stay with the solr server version 6.6.3

but the behaviour stays the same: no indexed documents from storage

---

Finaly (after a complete reinstall and reconfigure of all extensions and a new solr 6.6.3) the indexing starts, but (repeatedly) stalls at ~25%:

[image]

I already cleared the index and started indexing again: same result: ~25% and no further progress.

I have no clue what goes wrong, what error might occur, what to do to continue the indexing process. On the filestorage are 18572 files, so the 2642 Failures are not the remaining ~75%.

Where can I find out what stalls the indexing? Can I configure any logging?

Comment: I'd turn logging on in TS (at least exceptions, indexing and rawPost); it will write to a solr.log file in typo3temp/var/logs/ . I'd try to find out why there are 2642 failures already.
Next would be to see in the code which file is next for indexing and perhaps add some debug logging in the code to find out why it stops the indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Versionmatrix: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/Appendix/VersionMatrix.html

EXT:solr 8.1 needs ext:solrfal 5.1 and ext:tika 3.1

Comment: one step further